# Full heigth with media queries

Tags: css, html, media-queries

How can i get a div to be full height on my browser? im using media queries to get the full width of my body, but inside that body i have 3 divs that needs to be 100% full height always, even when i resize my browser.

This is what im using to get the body to be 100% width

```
@media only screen and (min-width:769px)
{

body{
background-color:red;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
min-width: 800px;
max-width: 1600px;
}
```

and there are 3 divs inside that body that i need to be 100% height always, the page that im making its not gonna have any scrolldowns, always has to be 100% height and 100% width

Comment: You could Google this, it has been asked before. Just in case this becomes a high result on Google: The html and body need to be set to 100% (or a fixed height of course) in order for containing elements to be set to a percentage height.

Comment: Yeah i google it, but i couldn't find the answer (maybe i was too desperate to see it), thanks a lot  for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is add this css:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.div-1 {
    height: 100%;
}
.div-2 {
    height: 100%;
}
.div-3 {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will make the height of divs 1, 2 and 3 the height of the browser always

Answer (score 0):

Try defining this

```
*, html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It will define every element to an 100% height as default, include your whole document body.

Comment: Thanks a lot i was going crazy about this